# Android notification set to 1 hour

Tags: android, time, timer, notifications

I'm trying to display a push notification to remind the user to check something they choose (do dishes, go to work, etc). I'd like to set it to current time + 1 hour for starters.

However I try the following code and it doesn't change anything (notification pops up immediately regardless of value I set)

```
 pushNotifAd.when = System.currentTimeMillis()+10000000;
```

Here's the complete code, please guide me how I can call it 1 hour after it's originally triggered:

```
//shows a notif on user tray, just pass the title and text!
public void pushNotif(String title,String text ){
    Context context = MainActivity.this
            .getApplicationContext();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    pushNotifAd = new Notification();
    pushNotifAd.icon = R.drawable.icon;
    pushNotifAd.tickerText = "time to go to work!";
    pushNotifAd.when = System.currentTimeMillis()+3600000;//current time + 1 // hr in millisecs


    Uri uri = Uri.parse("work.com");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);


    pushNotifAd.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Go to work!",
            "Time to get stuff done!", contentIntent);

    notificationManager
            .notify(LIST_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION, pushNotifAd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially set `pushNotifAd.when=System.currentTimeMillis();` and then
use `getMinutesDifference` method as

```
if (getMinutesDifference(pushNotifAd.when, System.currentTimeMillis()) > 60) {
    // use notification method here
}

private long getMinutesDifference(long timeStart, long timeStop) {
    long diff = timeStop - timeStart;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
    return diffMinutes;
}
```